# Databinding BR not working in my mvvm project in notifyPropertyChanged method

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to learn `mvvm` with a simple project but `BR` not working for me. I import `com.example.mvvm.BR` to my class but android studio show me cannot resolve symbol `BR`.

```
public class UserViewModel extends BaseObservable
{
    private String name;

    private Context context;

    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserViewModel(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);//error 
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is `BR`? If its related to `DataBinding` then Please add databinding tag and also modify your question's Title ..

Comment: Yes I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BR file is generated when the project is build. And will be cleared if you clean the project or any error occur during building the project. Try rebuilding the project. Build -> Rebuild Project. If there are no other errors and build is successful, then the BR will be resolved.